# Часть html кода с другим файлом css

Tags: html, css

У меня есть html код в связке с css, который писал другой программист.
Кусок этого html кода я вставляю на страницу в основном проекте. Если к этой странице подключить css, то начинаются конфликты с основным css из-за одинаковых названий классов и т.д.
Так вот собственно вопрос, можно ли как-то для куска html кода обозначить другой css файл?
Или может быть можно в html для определенного элемента написать что-то такое:

```
<div style="ref=ссылка на нужный css" class="vc_row_inner td_uid_20_5e74b63f09812_rand vc_row vc_inner wpb_row td-pb-row">
```

Answer (score 1):

Веб-компоненты. Только они поддерживаются не везде и может понадобиться полифил.

Но вообще-то, берёшь текстовый редактор и просто заменяешь конфликтующие имена классов.